wondering on performance of SCP over WAN
I'm using a scp to retrive log files from linux machine. On the way between the PC and the linux machine there is WAN simulator which can be configured to some latency and delay.
Setting the latency to 200ms I have terrible performance downloading the files from the linux machine compared to 20ms delay. No other parameter was changed.
I'd expect that there would be same performance. Any idea how can I find the source of the problem?

PS1: with tftp the performance is much better.
PS2: I have real environment on customer network - over the WAN (don't know their performance) where I suffer from same problem. However, similar environment without WAN, the performance is great.

That is normal. As the latency increases, the longer it takes for acknowledgement. 200 ms is a very bad latency, bordering on making VoIP unusable.

Compress the log files to a single archive first. Then transfer. That will make efficient use of a WAN connection.


Setting the latency to 200ms I have terrible performance downloading the files from the linux machine compared to 20ms delay.

While applications and protocols above the transport layer are really off topic here, that really sounds like a TCP issue. SCP's underlying SSH is based on TCP which uses a 'window' to determine the amount of data that may be in flight, ie. sent without being acknowledged by the destination.
With basic TCP, the maximum send window is 64 KiB. With a one-way latency of 200 ms = 400 ms round trip, the maximum throughput is 64 KiB/400 ms = 163 KB/s - no matter what actual bandwidth there is.
Your end points need to use the TCP scale option to increase the maximum window to ~1 GiB.

with tftp the performance is much better.

Off topic here, but TFTP is based on UDP. Classically, it uses a 'window' of just a single packet, which would be extremely slow over that link.
Microsoft has introduced a Windowsize option for TFTP, formalized in RFC 7440. It allows for up to 65535 blocks in flight (~96 MB), so you could get up to around 240 MB/s, more than a gigabit link can transmit.
Note that TFTP does not encrypt, so it shouldn't be used over WAN without encrypting encapsulation/VPN.
